# Fully featured time command on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, time, benchmarking

On some unix systems I've been used to a `time` command which many options including ways to format the output (`-f`) and redirect the output to a file (`-o`), see for example this man entry of [`time`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?time).

However on OS X it seems that we have a crippled down version that only has two (not so useful) options `-lp`. (I'm on Snow Leopard if that matters.)

So, how can I get a better `time` for my system?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have gtime in the [macports](https://trac.macports.org/), and in [homebrew](http://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/gnu-time.rb)

Comment: `brew install gnu-time`. The command is `gtime` though.

Answer (score 0):

The Fink project has lots of open source Unix software ported to OS X/Darwin:

http://finkproject.org/